# Show that the system of pairs of basis vectors is not a basis for the cartesian product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over an arbitrary field $K$, $B= (b_i)_{i \in I}$ basis of $V$, $C=(c_j)_{j \in J}$ basis of $W$.

I want to show that the system

$((b_i,c_j))_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$

is (in general) neither a generating system of $V \times W$ nor linearly independent.

I know that we have a basis of $V \times W$ by $((b_i, 0))_{i \in I} \cup ((0,c_j))_{j \in J}$, but I can not quite figure out the difference.

Every element of $V \times W$ can be written as

$(v,w) = \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i (b_i,0) + \sum_{j \in J} \beta_j (0,c_j)$ for some $\alpha_i, \beta_j \in K$.

But we can not write every element as
$(v,w) = \sum_{i,j} \lambda_{ij} (b_i, c_j)$ because $\lambda_{ij} \neq (\alpha_i \cdot \beta_j)$. Is this correct? That would show that it's not a generating system. And what about the linear independence?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the  example $V=W=\Bbb{R}$. Then $\{1\}\subseteq V=W$ is a basis for $V$ and $W$, but $\{(1,1)\}\subseteq V\times W$ is no generating system of $V\times W=\Bbb{R}^2$.

On the linear dependence: Take two bases of $\Bbb{R}³$, which have no elements in common, then the set of cartesian products of them has $9$ elements, which cannot be linearly independent in $\Bbb{R}^6$.